# Nativescript Vue: How to change frame height to account for space from other content?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have in my main `App.vue` a component, called `BottomNavigationBar` that is always on screen. Above that, I have a separate `Frame` that loads up `CountryListComponent`, which navigates to different parts of that component.  The only issue is that some of the content being loaded in the separate `Frame` is being hidden behind the persistent `BottomNavigationBar`.  I assume I have to adjust the height of the new `Frame` to lower the height to account for the `BottomNavigationBar`.  I added an `@loaded` event that called `adjustFrameHeight` to the `Frame` but not sure what to run inside of it to adjust the height.  What's the best way to do this?

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <DockLayout height="100%">

            <Frame @loaded="adjustFrameHeight" id="main-frame" height="90%" v-show="this.selectedTab =='1'">
                <CountryListComponent dock="top" @handleItemTap="handleItemTap" :movies="this.movies"/>
            </Frame>

            <BottomNavigationBar 
                        dock="bottom" 
                        activeColor="red"
                        inactiveColor="yellow"
                        backgroundColor="blue"
                        @tabSelected="this.changeTab"
                        verticalAlignment="bottom"
                        row="1">
                <BottomNavigationTab title="First" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Second" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Third" icon="icon-29.png" />
            </BottomNavigationBar>

        </DockLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a `GridLayout` instead of the `DockLayout`.
`*` will take up the available space on the screen and `auto` will take up the maximum height of the child component in that row.

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <GridLayout rows="*, auto" height="100%">

            <Frame row="0" @loaded="adjustFrameHeight" id="main-frame" height="100%" v-show="this.selectedTab =='1'">
                <CountryListComponent @handleItemTap="handleItemTap" :movies="this.movies"/>
            </Frame>

            <BottomNavigationBar 
                        row="1"
                        activeColor="red"
                        inactiveColor="yellow"
                        backgroundColor="blue"
                        @tabSelected="this.changeTab"
                        verticalAlignment="bottom">
                <BottomNavigationTab title="First" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Second" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Third" icon="icon-29.png" />
            </BottomNavigationBar>

        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks William.  I tried this out but the Frame still seems to be taking the entire height.  I confirmed this by setting the `BottomNavigationBar`'s backgroundColor to transparent and you can see the content of the Frame behind it.

Comment: @hectoraloneo try setting an explicit height on the `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: thanks again William.  No such luck...I added an explicit height to the BottomNavigationBar component and it shows on top of the the `Frame` still takes up 100% of the screen height so some of the Frame content is behind the BottomNavigationBar ....here is a  screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ZV3KUaE

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like Frame takes 100% of the height of its direct parent.
Just add StackLayout as the parent of the frame

```
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <GridLayout rows="*, auto" height="100%">
            <StackLayout>
               <Frame row="0" @loaded="adjustFrameHeight" id="main-frame" height="100%" v-show="this.selectedTab =='1'">
                  <CountryListComponent @handleItemTap="handleItemTap" :movies="this.movies"/>
               </Frame>
            </StackLayout>

            <BottomNavigationBar 
                        row="1"
                        activeColor="red"
                        inactiveColor="yellow"
                        backgroundColor="blue"
                        @tabSelected="this.changeTab"
                        verticalAlignment="bottom">
                <BottomNavigationTab title="First" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Second" icon="icon-29.png" />
                <BottomNavigationTab title="Third" icon="icon-29.png" />
            </BottomNavigationBar>

        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```